# Apache commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT: not found

Tags: sbt, maven-central

How can SBT builds be made reliable enough to use in a production environment?

Specifically, SBT normally builds without a problem, but every few weeks, the **commons-imaging** dependency is not found, halting the entire build.

In build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   , "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4"
   , "org.apache.commons" % "commons-imaging" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT" withSources ()
)

resolvers in ThisBuild ++= Seq(
   "Apache Development Snapshot Repository" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
)
```

**sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT: not found**

This usually works fine. But recently started giving:

```
[warn] Unable to reparse org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT from Apache Development Snapshot Repository
```

(1) Why would it be so intermittent? Is it the Resolver URL that changes, or the Web site that serves the commons-imaging jar going down? (other maven resources are found without ever experiencing a hiccup.)

(2) What can be done to ensure that clean builds always succeed? (This is crucial for spinning up a new instance and expecting it to succeed.)

Edit: This doesn't answer the question, but I found a workaround for this particular issue in that deleting "withSources()" allows the build to succeed.